# Between 20.04.5 LTS and latest LTS releases which should I choose?

Tags: system-installation, dell, ubuntu-drivers

Recently I have bought a Dell Inspiron 15 3511 laptop with the following specs:

Processor - 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-1115G4 @ 3.00 GHz 3.00 GHz

Ram- 8gb

Ssd- 512 gb

It also came with windows 11 home (single language) and office 21 suite. But windows 11 alone is consuming more than half of my ram and the system is hanging a lot. Now I want to switch to Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. But in the ubuntu certified laptops mine isn't listed. I am attaching the screenshot of it and pasting the link below.

[List of dell certified 3511 laptops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ywjA.jpg)

https://ubuntu.com/certified/laptops?offset=40

Will it be okay if I install ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS in my laptop? Will I be able to install it my laptop? I want to ask will my laptop work properly? Please help.

Also please suggest me which version of ubuntu should I choose.

Comment: Do not use 20.04, use 22.04.1 or soon to be updated to 22.04.2. I have Dell 3510 with 11th Gen Intel & SSD. It installed Kubuntu 22.04.1 without issue. I even forgot to change the UEFI settings required for older Ubuntu versions. I think that was because 22.04 enabled the VMD driver for the NVMe drive.  I did have to turn bitlocker off & turn Windows fast start up off.

Comment: So, should I install the latest release? What will happen if I go with 20.04?

Comment: Try 22.04 - you should always go for the latest LTS release..